# Configure Virtualhost to respond at specific domain

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I need configure apache to redirect on document root of website, only the request for domain name, ex.

if i type on browser https://my.domain.com i need view the website

if i type on browser https://ip_server i need view the apache courtesy page (Main DocumentRoot apache)

I tried to apply the domain name in VirtualHost directive but i have an SSL error

My file vhost (worked):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName my.domain.com
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteOptions Inherit
     JkMount       /idp/* worker1

     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mydomain"

ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
CustomLog logs/ssl_access_log trueip_combined
LogLevel warn

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard_mydomain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard_mydomain.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard_bundle_mydomain.com.ca-bundle

<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

In this way, if i type https://ip_server i view the website, there is a way to view the website just calling the host name (my.domain.com)?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with these lines before virtualhost of domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName catchall
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard_mydomain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/wildcard_mydomain.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/wildcard_bundle_mydomain.com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```